# JUnit Testing a Method with an Interface as the parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, interface

as the title states, i want to test the following Method:

```
Class A:

private List<String> s;
    
public A() {
    s = new ArrayList<String>();
    s.add("Gregor");
    s.add("Example");
    s.add("Example2");
}

public String argr(B b) { //B-> Interface
        int t = b.t();
        String r = "Hello ";
        for(String z:s ) {
            boolean x = b.f(t, 5);
            if(x) {
                r += z;
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
```

With the Interface B:

```
public interface B {
    int t();
    boolean f(int t, int i);
}
```

The Testing:

```
class Example{
  public B b;
  private A example = new A();

  @Test
  void test() {
    //assert(example .s() == "Hello GregorExampleExample2");
        
    System.out.println(example .s(b));
        
    //bsp.A(c);
    }
```

}

The Issue: method: b, requires an `Interface` as a parametere, the interface could be implemented via this Method: `Class A implements B{}`

Problem: When testing it doesn't recognize the interface implemented Methods in the Class A.

**Question 1**: How do you jUnit test an Method with an interface as a parameter?

**Question 2**: Do you need to implement the interface method in the jUnit test class, for it to work?

Comment: This is very confusing. Why would class A have a method that depends on B and at the same time implement B...?

But to answer one of you questions; yes you need to implement the interface B during unit testing. Junit can not do that for you

Comment: What do you want to model here. Pleas give A, B and arrg() better names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an anonymous class like this for every test case:

```
b = new B() {
    @Override
    public int t() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean f(int t, int i) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Just replace the return values with what suits your test case, but try to avoid putting any logic in the class (since then you would have to test it aswell).

If you don't want to implement the interface for every test case, another possibility is using Mockito to mock your interface:

```
B mock = Mockito.mock(B.class);
Mockito.when(mock.f(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(false);
```